# how to avoid to display white screen in ionic for ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Working with **ionic app for IOS**, I am facing one issue is that, when the app is open and then I click the `home button` of ios device. So then app is in background but after few seconds (may be after `~30 sec`). I am trying to open the app from task manager that time on ios app shows me white screen.

Please let me know how I can avoid to display such white screen in ionic.

Comment: any reply for this.

Comment: I had same issue, since last 6 month there is nothing solution. kindly share solution if anybody has. And this issue is now rejecting my app from Apple store

Comment: check your config.xml settings